# How to select values in multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, count

I have the following database structure:

```
car
+----------+------------+----------------+-----------------+
| car_id   | car_name   | car_model_id   | car_factory_id  |
+----------+------------+----------------+-----------------+

car_model
+---------------+----------------+
| car_model_id  | car_model_name |
+---------------+----------------+

factory
+-------------+---------------+-------------------+
| factory_id  | factory_name  | factory_location  |
+-------------+---------------+-------------------+

factory_location
+----------------------+------------------------+
| factory_location_id  | factory_location_name  |
+----------------------+------------------------+
```

I would like to:

- list all the Factories
- count the number of cars produced in each factory
- grouped by car_model

The output should be something like:

```
| factory_id | car_model_id = 1 | car_model_id = 2 | car_model_id = ... |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          |        145       |       3307       |         ...        |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 2          |       32798      |        345       |         ...        |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 3          |         0        |        10        |         ...        |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| ...        |        ...       |        ...       |         ...        |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

My closest try is this request, but it's still not what I want:
`SELECT COUNT(car_id) FROM car GROUP BY car_factory_id AND car_model_id`

My RDBMS is MySQL 5.1.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: ^ This, and look into inner joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, ;)

```
SELECT  a.factory_name , c.car_model_name,
        COUNT(b.car_factory_id) totalCount
FROM    factory a
        LEFT JOIN car b
            ON a.factory_id = b.car_factory_id
        LEFT JOIN car_model c
            ON b.car_model_id = c.car_model_id
GROUP BY a.factory_name , c.car_model_name
ORDER BY factory_name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You generally can't have the number of columns parameterized by values of the rows , the idiomatic way to do query for what you want with a sql database is to get something like this:

```
factory_id | car_model_id | count
1          | 1            | 145
1          | 2            | 3307
...
4          | 1            | 3245
4          | 2            | 38
```

In which case you would do:

```
SELECT factory_id, car_model_id, COUNT(*) FROM factory
INNER JOIN car ON factory_id = car_factory_id GROUP BY factory_id, car_model_id
```

Comment: Your request counts the number of cars produced for each `car_model_id` and do not pay attention to the `factory_id` parameter. The output looks like this: http://pastebin.com/0JitQehE

Comment: Seems to work correctly for me in this small test case.  https://gist.github.com/93de4b75d2f5718a08e3

Comment: I still don't understand why your request doesn't work... Anyway, thanks for the help and good luck for the Mortarboard badge :P